# PHP: do this || that (like javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, short, shorthand

In javascript we can use `||` to perform a second action if the first one fails, like:

```
function getObject(id_or_object) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id_or_object) || id_or_object;
    return obj;
}
```

How can we do this in PHP?

If we can't, I can swear I have seen this `||` used like this in PHP. What does it mean?

I want to do:

```
function fix_item($item) {
    $item['armor'] = $item['armor'] || 0;
    return $item;
}
```

But this doesn't work, so I'm using

```
function fix_item($item) {
    if (!isset($item['armor'])) $item['armor'] = 0;
    return $item;
}
```

, but I don't like the second method.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `||` (`OR`) for true/false comparison, but (this is one of the known (arguable) design errors) in PHP's design: short-circuit doesn't return the operand's value (as you were doing in your javascript-logic example) but the boolean result.

That means that:
`$item['armor'] = $item['armor'] || 0;`
does not work as you intended (like it would in javascript).
Instead, it would set `$item['armor']` to boolean true/false (depending on the outcome of: `$item['armor'] || 0` ).

However, one *can* use the 'lazy evaluation' in a similar manner as you can use it in javascript:
`isset($item['armor']) || $item['armor'] = 0;`
(with an added `isset` to prevent an `Undefined variable` error).
It still clearly describes what your intention is and you don't need to invert the boolean `isset` result using `!` (which would be nececary for `if` and `&&` (`AND`)).

Alternatively, one can also do:
`$item['armor'] = $item['armor'] OR $item['armor'] = 0;`  (note that this will give an `E_NOTICE`)
(I think readability is not so good),

or ternary:
`$item['armor'] = isset($item['armor']) ? $item['armor'] : 0;`
(with 'better'/'more common' readabilty, but added code-size).

For PHP7 and up, see [Tom DDD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30519438/588079) 's answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using php 7 you can use the null coalesce operator

```
$a ?? $b ?? $c
```

this evaluates to the first non null value. Which is very simmilar to the || from javascript.

Comment: PHP 7 isn't generally available yet.

Answer (score 1):

This tests $item['armor'], if it is true it returns what is to the right of the ? operator, if it is false it returns what is immediately to the right of : (I've used the ternary operator in javascript, too).

```
function fix_item($item) {
    $item['armor'] = $item['armor'] ? $item['armor'] : 0;
    return $item;
}
```

Comment: You've missed `:` somewhere.

Comment: You're totally right!function fix_item($item) {
    $item['armor'] = $item['armor'] ? $item['armor'] : 0;
    return $item;
}

Comment: So why not fix the answer?